# How to find a cretin point in a excel file

Tags: excel, data-extraction, vba

I am trying to find the values at a cretin point in a excel data-set. 
[image]

I am looking for the area in red.

Any help would be great Thank

Comment: put your cursor on the point you desire... Or right click the chart and add labels..

Comment: That will show me the data, but i want to extract it

Comment: What do you mean by extract? Do you want to know the location of the cells the chart is built on?

Comment: No i wanted to know how many data points where located within the circle

Comment: *i wanted to know how many data points where located within the circle* - click on the blue line and count that data point labels...

Comment: What defines the circle?  Why is it drawn around those specific points?  It would help if you explain that part. PS "cretin" >> "certain" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question:

I counted the values within the red circle, by using:

```
countif (setting the criteria (so the value would count the values i wanted)
and set a ranger (so it wouldn't count anywhere else)
```

So for the bad description, and thanks to those who gave me ideas.

Niall